# ThreeJS MeshStandardMaterial is too slow in mobile device compared to MeshBasicMaterial

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have following code to add cube in the scene, when I open the page  in browser on PC it works fine, but when I open in mobile device the control is too slow. It takes 3-4 second to get response from the touch and mobile also getting slow.

Where as if I changed the `MeshStandardMaterial` to MeshBasicMaterial everything goes normal. What could be the issue.

```
sideWallMaterial = [new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    roughness: 0.8,
    metalness: 0.2,
    bumpScale: 0.0055
  }),
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: '#a6aea2',
    roughness: 0.8,
    metalness: 0.2,
    bumpScale: 0.0005,
    opacity: 0.5,
    transparent: true,
    depthWrite: false
  }),
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: '#a6aea2',
    roughness: 0.8,
    metalness: 0.2,
    bumpScale: 0.0005
  }),
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: '#a6aea2',
    roughness: 0.8,
    metalness: 0.2,
    bumpScale: 0.0005
  }),
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: '#a6aea2',
    roughness: 0.8,
    metalness: 0.2,
    bumpScale: 0.0005
  }),
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: '#a6aea2',
    roughness: 0.8,
    metalness: 0.2,
    bumpScale: 0.0005
  })
];

var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
textureLoader.load("img1.jpg", function(map) {
  map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  map.anisotropy = 4;
  map.repeat.set(10, 10);
  sideWallMaterial[0].map = map;
  sideWallMaterial[0].needsUpdate = true;

});
textureLoader.load("img2.jpg", function(map) {

  map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  map.anisotropy = 4;
  map.repeat.set(10, 10);
  sideWallMaterial[0].bumpMap = map;
  sideWallMaterial[0].needsUpdate = true;

});
textureLoader.load("img3.jpg", function(map) {

  map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  map.anisotropy = 4;
  map.repeat.set(10, 24);
  sideWallMaterial[0].roughnessMap = map;
  sideWallMaterial[0].needsUpdate = true;

});

var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(wall_t, wall_h, wall_w);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, sideWallMaterial);
mesh.receiveShadow = true;
mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Answer (score 2):

`MeshStandardMaterial` is a PBR material whereas `MeshBasicMaterial` is an unlit material. So the rendering performance of the latter one is much better. However, it does not react on any lights so its simple visual appearance is not comparable to the more advanced `MeshStandardMaterial`.

Also keep in mind that not all materials have the same properties. You can assign a bump and roughness map to `MeshStandardMaterial` but not to `MeshBasicMaterial` or `MeshLambertMaterial` (which you have used in your code snippet). These textures are just ignored by both materials which means you save the respective texture decode and GPU upload. This will of course improve the initial "compile/display" performance.

`three.js R108`